# Paramiko ssh -X option

Tags: ssh, xorg

is it possible to open a ssh connection passing through Paramiko, as if we had used the command "ssh -X ...", for X11 management by the Server X ?

Thank you for your help,

Regards

Comment: Not sure why this was migrated here. If we tag this with *python*, would it be possible to move it back to SO?

Comment: The kind you ask may confuse some of the admin. Paramiko is not that flying word I think. And the rest of that question is ssh related superuser stuff X)

Comment: The thing is that Paramiko is a Python module and to open an SSH connection with it, you need to write Python code. It's not really a question about SSH.

Answer (score 1):

From the [paramiko.Channel documentation](http://www.bitpim.org/apidoc/public/paramiko.Channel-class.html#request_x11):

> request_x11(self, screen_number=0, auth_protocol=None, auth_cookie=None, single_connection=False, handler=None)
>
> Request an x11 session on this channel. If the server allows it, further x11 requests can be made from the server to the client, when an x11 application is run in a shell session.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7678973/183066) to a similar question in SO (it looks by the same author), provides more information with regard to the `handler` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the paramiko code, I realized that paramiko only implements a way to establish an x11 channel. It does not connect the channel to the local x11 display. That is left to you.

Please see this answer for a working example of how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903844/72911